# How to group by multiple columns respectively in Hive SQL?

Tags: sql, group-by, hive, count

Suppose that I have a table named `t`, with two columns `foo` and `bar`.

| foo | bar |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 11 |
| 1 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 2 | 11 |
| 3 | 11 |
| 3 | 12 |
| 3 | 12 |

Now I would like to calculate the occurrences of different values for `foo` and `bar` separately and aggregate them into an `ARRAY<MAP<BIGINT, BIGINT>>`.

In this example:

- `foo == 1` appeared 2 times;
- `foo = 2` appeared 3 times;
- `foo = 3` appeared 3 times;
- `bar == 11` appeared 6 times;
- `bar == 12` appeared 2 times.

So, the resulting table should look like this:

| name | cnt |
| --- | --- |
| "foo" | [{1:2}, {2:3}, {3:3}] |
| "bar" | [{11:6}, {12:2}] |

My current approach is somewhat like this:

```
WITH t_foo AS (
  SELECT
    "foo" AS name,
   COLLECT_LIST(MAP(val, cnt)) AS cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT
      foo AS val,
      COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
      t
    GROUP BY
      foo
  ) AS tt
),
t_bar AS (
  SELECT
    "bar" AS name,
   COLLECT_LIST(MAP(val, cnt)) AS cnt
  FROM (
    SELECT
      bar AS val,
      COUNT(*) AS cnt
    FROM
      t
    GROUP BY
      bar
  ) AS tt
)
SELECT * FROM t_foo
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM t_bar
```

This works, but it seems rather repetitive. In fact, I have not only `foo` and `bar`, but also more than a dozen other columns to deal with. Is there a smarter way to solve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to generalize this code, you should need dynamic querying, yet that approach can be heavy and prone to sql injection attacks.

Yet you can still do something without using dynamic querying, and that is:

- compute all your counts at once, using window functions instead of aggregations
- applying the union all of `COLLECT_LIST` operations.

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT DISTINCT foo, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY foo) AS cnt_foo,
                    bar, COUNT(*) OVER(PARTITION BY bar) AS cnt_bar
    FROM t
)
SELECT "foo" AS name, COLLECT_LIST(MAP(foo, cnt_foo)) AS cnt FROM cte
UNION ALL 
SELECT "bar" AS name, COLLECT_LIST(MAP(bar, cnt_bar)) AS cnt FROM cte
```

Should perform better than the original.

Comment: nice shot! thks!